# How to autostart svnserve on reboot and specify the default svn path?

Tags: centos, svn, svn-server

I'm trying to transfer a working subversion Ubuntu server to a CentOS server.
Right now I just use `svnserve`, since I see no need for running it as an Apache module.

I installed svn on CentOS with

```
yum install subversion
```

Now I can create a repository with

```
svnadmin create reponame
```

and start it with

```
svnserve -d
```

Two things are bothering me though :

- I need svnserve to autostart on reboot.
- I want to use short paths, like `svn://domain.com/reponame`

instead of `svn://domain.com/home/svn/reponame`
(I created the repository 'reponame' in /home/svn)

I know this can be done with the `-r` parameter ,  but is there somewhere a config file to 
set the default location ?   And how would this work together with the autostart configuration?

Comment: You could put `svnserve -d -r /directory/with/svn/repos` into an init script.